# Rename column entries from another column in R

Tags: r

Simplified example, sample data:

```
data_f <- data.frame(id=rep(1:10),cat=rep("non",10),nam=paste(rep(1:10),rep(1:10),letters[1:10],sep=""))
data_f[,2] <- c("one","","","two","","tree","","four","","")

data_d <- data.frame(nam1=paste(rep(1:10),rep(1:10),letters[1:10],sep=""))
```

Desired result:

```
      nam1  new.name
1     11 a       one   
2     22 b       one
3     33 c       one
4     44 d       two
5     55 e       two
6     66 f       tree 
7     77 g       tree
8     88 h       four
9     99 i       four
10    1010 j     four
```

In words: if any entries of column `nam` matches `nam1` from `data_d` take its category, that's column `cat` from `data_f` and place it next to the corresponding value of `nam1`. Please note that the entries of `nam1` and `nam` are scattered randomly not in order as in example.

I'm failing to find efficient solution to this.

Comment: Could you develop it a bit? what is to be changed in column 2? Entries? Based on what?

Comment: @PauloCardoso, I explained it fuhrer by words. Hope it is clearer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one possibility:

```
merge(data_d, 
      transform(data_f[-1], cat = ave(cat, cumsum(cat != ""), FUN = function(x) x[1])), 
      by.x = "nam1", by.y = "nam", sort = FALSE)
```

The result:

```
    nam1  cat
1    11a  one
2    22b  one
3    33c  one
4    44d  two
5    55e  two
6    66f tree
7    77g tree
8    88h four
9    99i four
10 1010j four
```